# MaTeX: how to control horizontal alignment of the resulting object?

Tags: graphics, text

When I use MaTeX, I find that the displayed text is always centered with respect to the specified location. Adding `TextAlignment -> Left` seems to be ignored:
`Graphics[Text[MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 4], {0, 0}, TextAlignment -> Left]]`

Is there a way to control where the string starts?

Comment: You should probably ping @Szabolcs, the creator of that package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TextAlignment` is not an option of `Text`. The standard way to align text when using `Text` as a `Graphics` primitive is to use the optional third argument which represents an offset. This works with `MaTeX` or just plain text.

Also, it would probably best to include some other objects in your image so that we can see what's going on.

Thus, maybe you want something like:

```
Graphics[{
 {LightGray, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},
  Point[{0, 0}],
 Text[MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 2], {0, 0}, {1, 0}]
}]
```

[image]

**Update:**  [Mathematica 11.1 and 11.2 are affected by a bug where `Text` offsetting does not work correctly.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156121/12)  To work around the problem, use

```
Text[MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 2], {0, 0}, ImageScaled[{1, 1/2}]]
```

instead of

```
Text[MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 2], {0, 0}, {1, 0}]
```

Comment: Thank you, This did it. So MaTeX produces an object without any awareness of its position and Graphics lays it out?

Comment: What's the default value for the offset? It seems to change the behavior qualitatively: rather than putting the center of an object at a particular point, it puts the bottom left corner.

Comment: @Lem.ma Mathematica 11.1 and 11.2 are affected by a bug where `Text` positioning does not work correctly. To work around this problem, use `ImageScaled[{1,1/2}]` instead of `{1,0}` in the third argument of `Text`.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: I would use `Inset` instead.

The output of `` MaTeX` `` is a graphic, not text:

```
MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 2] // FullForm // Shallow
```

> `Graphics[List[Skeleton[2]],List[Skeleton[6]]]`

The thing about `Text` is that it turns ordinary expressions into expressions suitable for display. For example, it turns x^2 into $x^2$. Since the output of `` MaTeX` `` is a graphic, `Text` is not the most natural choice here. I would instead go with `Inset`:

```
Graphics[{
  {LightGray, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[{0, 0}, 1]},
  Inset[MaTeX["a=b+c+d", Magnification -> 2], {-0.5, 0.2}]
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `Inset` has an additional argument called `opos` which can be used to determine the relationship between the text and the given position. To simulate left justification, one might set it to `{Left, Center}`.

Comment: I think `Inset` and `Text` are almost interchangeable. Can you see any difference between them when using only 1-3 arguments?  They don't only hold text/graphics, they (both) hold *anything* that can appear inline in a notebook: text, graphics, 2D math, GUI elements, grids, tables, etc.  AFAIK most things that appear in a notebook have a BaselinePosition option, which allows them to flow well together with text (MaTeX tries to set the baseline appropriately, but unfortunately the result does not always look great because the front end rounds to integer pixels)

Comment: @Szabolcs I agree with you, but I think it is misleading to apply `Text` to something which is not text. If you read the code quickly, it might look as though `Text` is rendering the expression (generating the display form.) In fact, it is MaTeX which does that. Better then to use a head which does not affect the display form, so that readers who skim the code (or do not know what MaTeX is) cannot make that mistake. In fact, I'm not sure whether OP chose `Text` because he knew that `Text` and `Inset` are the same in this case, or because he thought he was dealing with text.

Comment: This response helped me understand that the output of MaTeX is an object suitable to display, but it doesn't solve the problem with not being able to control where the text starts.

Comment: @Lem.ma Maybe you do not properly understand how to use the `opos` argument of `Inset`. For left justification it should be set to `{Left, Center}`. Tell me if this doesn't solve your problem.