# SciDraw: How to left-align a FigLabel text?

Tags: scidraw

In `SciDraw`, the following command

```
FigLabel[{0.2, 0.3}, "test"];
```

places the label "test" at `x=0.2` and `y=0.3` in the current plot. Now, by default the text is centered around this point. Is there a way to make it start at the given point?

The argument `Position->{x,y}` doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave a more detailed description in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152966/12).  Here's a summary:

To specify the alignment relative to the anchor point `{x,y}` in `FigLabel[{x,y}, "label"]`, you can use either

```
FigLabel[Anchor[{x,y}, offset], "label"]
```

or

```
FigLabel[{x,y}, "label", TextOffset -> offset]
```

The `offset` value is similar to the third argument of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) and can take either a named specification such as `Left` or a scaled coordinate pair running in the range `-1..1`. Thus `{-1,0}` is equivalent to `Left`.

Relevant sections of the SciDraw manual:

- 8.1.8 Text positioning
- 7.1 Points and anchors
- 13 Annotations

Answer (score 2):

@Felix: The only way I've found around this is using old-school `Text[]`.

```
Quiet@Get["SciDraw`"]
```

Define

```
tlg = Graphics@Text["Center", {5, 6}, {-1, 0}] (* left-j *);
trg = Graphics@Text["Center", {5, 6}, {+1, 0}] (* right-j *);
```

then

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[{
   FigLabel[{5, 5}, "Center"],
   FigGraphics@tlg,
   FigGraphics@trg,
   FigLine[{{5, 0}, {5, 10}}],
   FigLine[{{0, 5}, {10, 5}}]
   },
  XPlotRange -> {0, 10},
  YPlotRange -> {0, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

`ScaledLabel` (`FigLabel` in `SciDraw`) has been great for Single lines. Not so for multi-line text blocks where I want proper justification.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I needed! Just to add, to align `MaTeX` text, one can combine this approach with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144091/ to get `tlg2 = Graphics[
   Inset[MaTeX["\\text{Center}", 
     Magnification -> .05], {5, 6}, {Left, Center}]];`.

Comment: See my answer for a pure-SciDra way.