# SciDraw: Insert MaTeX text without distortion

Tags: scidraw, matex

This question is related to [aligning MaTeX text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/144091/) and [aligning in SciDraw](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152606/). Following the solution in these questions, I can position and align `MaTeX` text in `SciDraw` with respect to a well defined point. The problem now is that the text is huge and distorted, i.e., it scales with the aspect ratio of the plot. Below, see my attempts to fix the distortion by setting the size of the graphics to the same size as the plot.

How can this be done properly, i.e., inserting the `MaTeX` graphics without scaling and distortion?

```
Quiet@Get["SciDraw`"]
<< "MaTeX`"
tlg2 = Graphics[
        Inset[MaTeX["x=1", Magnification -> .5],
               {5, 5}, {Left, Center}, {50, Automatic}],
        ImageSize -> {50, Automatic}, 
        PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}];
Figure[
 FigurePanel[{
  FigGraphics@tlg2,
  FigLine[{{5, 0}, {5, 10}}], 
  FigLine[{{0, 5}, {50, 5}}]}, 
 XPlotRange -> {0, 50}, 
 YPlotRange -> {0, 10}]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know if this is the best way, but it appears to work well:

- Use `FigLabel`, the object intended for label construction in SciDraw
- Specify an offset for the label

The offset can be given as

```
FigLabel[Anchor[{x,y}, offset], "label"]
```

or as

```
FigLabel[{x,y}, "label", TextOffset -> offset]
```

The offset specification is similar to the third argument of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) (see under Details in the docs), and can take either a scaled coordinate pair running from `-1..1` or a named specification such as `Left`.

Thus you could use

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[{
   FigLabel[{5, 5}, MaTeX["x=1", FontSize -> 24], 
    TextOffset -> Left];
   FigLine[{{5, 0}, {5, 10}}], FigLine[{{0, 5}, {50, 5}}]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Instead of `Left` we could have used `{-1,0}`. This means that the anchor point (`{5,5}` here) is at scaled position `{-1,0}` inside of the label.

To use the bottom left as the anchor, use `{-1,-1}`.  Then we obtain this:

[image]

It looks like as if there were too much space left below the label. This empty space is, in fact, part of the label graphics, and is there to leave room for characters with descenders such as `g` or `y`.  You can ask MaTeX to crop tightly around the label using `ContentPadding -> False`.

```
Figure[
 FigurePanel[{
   FigLabel[{5, 5}, 
    MaTeX["x=1", FontSize -> 24, ContentPadding -> False], 
    TextOffset -> {-1, -1}];
   FigLine[{{5, 0}, {5, 10}}], FigLine[{{0, 5}, {50, 5}}]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{0, 50}, {0, 10}}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thank you, this was really what I was looking for!