# Text[] with offset not positioned correctly in M11.1 and M11.2

Tags: graphics, bugs, matex

**Bug introduced in 11.1 and persisting through 11.3**

---

When the first argument of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html) is a `Graphics`, and the third argument (offset) is used, positioning is incorrect in M11.1 and M11.2.  Mathematica 11.0 behaves correctly.

Example:

```
inset = Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 2]}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> None, ImagePadding -> 1, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
  ImageSize -> 90]
```

[image: Inset]

```
figure = Graphics[
  {Text[inset, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {1, 1}]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  Frame -> True,
  GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, .1], Range[0, 1, .1]},
  ImageSize -> 360
  ]
```

[image: Incorrect positioning]

<sup>(This is wrong)</sup>

With the `{1,1}` offset, the upper right corner of the inset should line up with the middle of the plot range in the enclosing figure.

In Mathematica 11.0 we get the expected output:

[image: Correct positioning]

In M11.1 and 11.2 we also get a correct positioning if the inset is a general notebook expression instead of a `Graphics`.  We can, for example, wrap it in `Framed` to achieve this.

```
figure = Graphics[
  {Text[Framed[inset], Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {1, 1}]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}},
  Frame -> True,
  GridLines -> {Range[0, 1, .1], Range[0, 1, .1]},
  ImageSize -> 360
  ]
```

[image: Correct positioning with Framed]

Is there a workaround for this bug?

---

This bug is of concern to me because [`MaTeX`](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX)-generated expressions are supposed to be a drop-in replacement for text.  It is supposed to work when written directly within `Text`.   But `MaTeX` outputs `Graphics`, so it is affected by this bug. In some situations, the user can't even control if some expression they input will be used inside of a `Text` or an `Inset`.

Comment: Exceptionally, I am tagging this as [tag:bugs] from the beginning as it has been confirmed by support in CASE:3943734.

Answer (score 7):

Skip to the end for a workaround.

#### Understanding the bug

To understand the underlying cause of the bug, let us cycle `figure` through a box representation and look at its input form. This can be done by converting the output cell to input form (Command-Shift-I) or programmatically using

```
InputForm@ToExpression@ToBoxes[figure]
```

Notice that instead of `Text`, in 11.1 and 11.2 now we have an `Inset` equivalent to

```
Inset[inset, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], {1,1}]
```

In 11.0, we have

```
Inset[inset, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], ImageScaled[{1,1}]]
```

Looking at the documentation of [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html), we see that the third argument is interpreted as a position within `inset`.  If `inset` is a general notebook expression (like `Framed` or text), then the offset position goes from 0..1.  If `inset` is `Graphics` it is interpreted as plot coordinates.

In `Text`, however, it is supposed to go from -1..1 regardless of what expression `Text` contains.

When converting a `Text` to an `Inset`, the offset position must be converted too.  `{1,1}` should convert to `ImageScaled[{1,1}]` and `{-1,-1}` should convert to `ImageScaled[{0,0}]`.  See [`ImageScaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageScaled.html).

This conversion does happen in M11.0 and earlier but not in M11.1 and M11.2.

#### The workaround

The workaround is to use `ImageScaled` directly within `Text`:

```
Text[inset, Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}], ImageScaled[{0, 0}]]
```

Of course, if we do so, we might as well use [`Inset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) instead of [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html).  However, both work when the offset coordinates are `ImageScaled`.

If you cannot control whether `Inset` or `Text` is going to be used in some context, use `Framed[inset, FrameMargins -> None, FrameStyle -> None]`. This *does* add a tiny margin, but in practice it is very usable.