# Can MaTeX objects scale the same way as Text objects?

Tags: graphics, text, matex

When one uses

```
Text[Style["Hi", FontSize -> Scaled[.1]]]
```

the text will resize proportional with `Imagesize`?

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior with objects produced by MaTeX? In my experience MaTeX objects stay the same absolute size when the Graphics object is rescaled.

Comment: `MaTeX` returns a graphics: `t = MaTeX["\\Gamma"];
Head[t]`; to scale it, use e.g. `Magnify[t, 5]`

Comment: or `Show[t, ImageSize -> Scaled[.1]]`

Comment: It is probably useful for you to be aware of the following bug in Mathematica (and its workaround): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/156121/12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MaTeX returns a `Graphics` expression.  You can include it in some enclosing graphics using `Text` or `Inset`.  E.g. `Inset` allows scaled sizing.

Non-scaled:

```
Graphics[{Inset@Graphics@Disk[]}, Frame -> True]
```

Scaled:

```
Graphics[{Inset[Graphics@Disk[], Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[0.5]]}, Frame -> True]
```

However, I strongly recommend *not* using scaled sizing. MaTeX is meant for creating publication quality figures.  With these, it is important to be in control of figure and font sizing. That means that you should target a certain physical size both for your figure (e.g. 8 cm) and your fonts (e.g. 10 printer's points). This way you can ensure that the figure will be readable, and that the font size within the figure will match well with the font size of the surrounding text.

Isn't it so ugly and sloppy looking when an arXiv preprint has 1 cm size letters when printed on paper, or unreadable 2 mm letters?  That happens because people don't think about what size their figure (and the text within) should be.